# Auto-Completion in Mac OS X Terminal – custom word list

Tags: macos, bash, autocomplete, terminal

I would like to auto-complete the arguments in my function `foo`. I want to store a list of possible arguments like this: `bar,baba,gugu`.

So when I type `foo b[TAB]`in Terminal, I would like to have the recommendations of `bar` and `baba`.

Comment: Take a look on this URL first: http://www.caliban.org/bash/#completion_standard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go: http://freecode.com/projects/bashcompletion

You can install it via brew: `brew install bash-completion`. During installation brew will say what to do next - add some lines to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Take a look at [README](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git;a=blob_plain;f=README) for instructions on how to add custom completions

Comment: Be sure to `brew install git` before installing bash completion if you want to use Git auto completion!